# perl remove two slashes regex

Tags: perl, regex

I have file wich has many lines inside

All lines that contain

```
file=/aaaaaaa/bbbbbbb/cccccc/dddddd.txt
```

it needs to be stripped to this format

```
file=/dddddd.txt
```

i am executing perl in bash somethin like this

```
perl -i -pe 'regex' /localpath/file.txt
```

In perl command above in 'regex' i would need command to do it, how to do it ?

Comment: General unix questions like this (not specifically related to system administration) should be asked on [unix.se] (or [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) if they're basic programming) - this kind of "gimmeh teh c0dez" question isn't really on-topic for Server Fault.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to extract the file, I would use [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -n -e 'print $1.$2."\n"if (/(.+\=)\/.+\/.+\/.+(\/.+)$/)' /localpath/file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Theres probably more elegant ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 perl -ne '/(.*=).*\/(.*)$/ && print "$1/$2\n"' /localpath/file
```